# Replace a monitor that is humming?

Tags: display, desktop-computer

The monitor for my desktop hums/buzzes when a have a white background with a lot of black text maximized. I'm sure it would do it in other cases but this is the most obvious. I usually hear it when I am looking at a text file in an SSH client.

What causes this? Is it clear that it is time for a new monitor?

I can provide details about my hardware if that will help.

It's a Dell 2001FP.

Comment: Please provide details about your hardware, it will help.

Comment: Is it a CRT? Its about time to replace it. If its a LCD, power supply- will die soon.

Comment: could be the power cable have you tried a different one?

Comment: Maybe there is a repair kit for the LCD... http://www.ebay.com/itm/Repair-Kit-Samsung-214T-LCD-Monitor-Capacitors-/230554161051?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item35ae194f9b

Comment: Does it hum a good tune?

Comment: Why would you ask if it's a CRT when he put the model right there?  Good GAWD it says FP right at the end you didn't even need to GOOGLE it!!  LOL

Comment: because "edited 37 mins ago"... "asked 1 hour ago".

Comment: He did.. skimming fail.. still. CRT.. replace.

Comment: Go buy another one the same model, then put this on in and return it as faulty.

Comment: @ppumkin: First, this if fraud, second, many shops record the S/N of the equipment they sell, so they will know.

Comment: Pumpkin... yer a devious SOB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LCD monitor's backlight is a fluorescent tube (The [specs](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/monitors/2001fp/EN/specs.htm) specifically say CCFL). The backlight's power inverter sometimes hums, or makes other noises. This is only indicative of low quality of the some of its components, usually it **does not** mean the monitor is about to fail soon.

### How to fix

Adjusting the brightness nearly always helps to at least reduce the humming, or change its frequency to make it less irritating. The exact best brightness level can only be found by experimentation. E.g. start with 100%, reduce one step, wait 2-3 secs and listen... You'll find a couple of brightness levels that will sound better than the rest.

Unfortunately, there is not much else you can do about it.

Comment: except of course, REPLACE it like I said LOL.  I guess the question is... do you want to "reduce" the issue?  Or do you want to "solve" the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If its a CRT, try degaussing it (it'll be an option upon the on screen menu built into it usually). That sometimes used to help for me, anyhow.

If its an LCD, try lowering the brightness setting to 60% (which is usually easier on the eyes also) as they usually leave the shop cranked right up.

Comment: It's a Dell 2001FP. The brightness is at 50%.

Comment: Model number gives the very first detail you asked for without even Googling it

Comment: In fairness, I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know... try to note that in the edit :)  I tried to un downvote but it no let me :(  Sorry.

Comment: Degaussing wont solve a power supply hum.. seriously?! WTF

Comment: If it even is a power supply hum.

Answer (score -1):

Obviously it's NOT a CRT, the model no that you kindly posted says FP at the end (mind you that is if I was too lazy to google it)... Pay attention folks.  Aside from that, the thing is a tiny LCD - Buy a new decent sized one unless yer broke.  Yes the buzz is indicative of an impending failure but it could be in five minutes or five years.  It's Christmas time, spoil yerself and recycle this one properly.

Comment: meh. It's a work machine.

Comment: OG, the model number has only just been added to the question.

Comment: Then it should be made clear that's an added edit.

Comment: And if this is a work monitor, why even debate this?  Spend their money and move on :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure not every company is rolling in cash.

Comment: Fair enough.  Consider that model is several years old and humming at him, I'd hardly consider such an expenditure require the company be "rolling" in cash.  Further, if they can't afford a monitor... you should probably be job hunting by now and worried about cashing your paycheck.